# Use expression in winform chart y Series

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, charts

In my winform app ,

1. I want to use chart from toolbox (instead of making on using RDLC  report).
2. But in Y axis I want to use expression like `=Count((Fields!Number.Value))` but the chart won't allow me to as it simply takes names of he column.
3. I have tried searching in web but didn't find convincing result. So please share any link or share your knowledge so that I can learn

I also looked at coding options like `chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, 0);` but I have  no idea how to enter expression in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my search, It is hard for us to find a method to use expression directly.

However, I suggest that you can define a method to replace the expression, then you can add the correspond point when you want to use the expression.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            var series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
            {
                Name = "Series1",
                Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
                IsVisibleInLegend = false,
                IsXValueIndexed = true,
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };

            this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                series1.Points.AddXY(i, Result(i));
            }
            chart1.Invalidate();
        }

        private int Result(int i)
        {
            var result = 20 * i + i * i;
            return result;
        }
```

Result:
[image]